# How to select a group of characters in a string using regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am new to regular expression. I am trying to match a group of characters using regular expression, but it does not work.

Here is my code.

```
    string test = "Hello$@%$all";
    string regex = "($@%$)";
    string result = Regex.Replace(test, regex, "\n");
```

Any help??

Comment: When posting code, select the code and press the {Code Sample} button or alternatively, press Ctrl+K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the characters that has special meaning in regular expressions.

```
string test = "Hello$@%$all";
string regex = @"\$@%\$";
string result = Regex.Replace(test, regex, "\n");
```

Characters like `$` has special meaning when used in a regular expression. So tell apart whether it's a character used to signify something in the expression or whether you need to literally match that character, you can escape it using a `\`